# How to create conditional questions in a form for an ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, forms

How can I dynamically add additional text fields to a view based on the response to previous question which is a drop down with set list of options.

The issue I am having is with dynamic positioning. For example if I place the field beneath but keep it hidden and show when an option is selected that only works one way. What if I select the other option how can I use the same space to show a different question/text field?

Of course I could overlay all of the options in their positions and show/hide. But is there a better way to build a dynamic form with conditional logic for questions?

Diagram:
[image: Form flow]

Comment: Are you ever going to have more than 1 option at a time?

Comment: Not simultaneously. So for example if you respond to question number 2 with answer a, you will see two specific follow up questions. If you had responded with answer b, you would skip the follow up question should be presented with the remaining questions. So my objective is to be able to slot in fields dynamically reusing using the same the space. If you went back and changed your answer, the follow up questions should also disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, to make it simple for both myself and the viewer, I would have predefined space. Say, 20% of the view. Then, add questions to the scrollView variably, depending on the situation. The user can then scroll through that view.

```
let rect = CGRect(x: view.frame.width*0.1, y: someHeightDownInTheView, width: view.frame.width*0.8, height: view.frame.height*0.2)
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: rect)

let questions = ["Do I want to be a unicorn"]
if(question2.answer == "A") { 
    questions.append("Do I want to be a fairy princess")
}
//...Specific options

for question in questions {
    let label:UILabel = createQuestion(name: "someName", question: question)
    let answer:UITextView = createAnswer(name: "someName")
    scrollView.addSubview(label)
    scrollView.addSubview(answer)
}

func createQuestion(name: String, question: String) -> UILabel {
    //Create a question with a UILabel of some SET SIZE
}

func createAnswer(name: String) -> UITextView {
    //Create answer with a UITextView of some SIZE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle variable numbers of fields.

You could create a table view or collection view, and have each cell, or each grouped set of cells, represent a question and its text field.

You could also use a vertical stack view. You can add or remove items from a stack view and it updates make room for/close up empty space as needed.

There are tons of examples of both approaches online. Which is the best fit depends on the details, but if you only ever have at most 2 questions/answers on-screen then maybe a stack view is the way to go.

Comment: Thx, I've searched around a lot, struggling to find examples for either. Are you able to share here in response to the question?

Comment: Do you have a sketch of the look you're after?

Comment: I have just added a sketch to the original question describing the flow and look. As you can see what I'm trying to achieve is reuse of space based on conditional logic as you work through the form. Also only the current question and any ones above should show at any point, nothing below until a selection is made and the form builds itself out gradually. Thx